# Select data for running total graph using Transact SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, graph, cumulative-sum

I have a table with following structure:
AuthorId, FollowersNumber, PublishDate, ...
What I need is to draw graph of a running total of FollowersNumber by periods. Tricky thing is that every author is counted only once. For example for following table:

```
AuthorId, FollowersNumber, PublishDate
1         100              '2013-01-01'
2         200              '2013-01-01'
3         200              '2013-01-02'
2         100              '2013-01-02'
4          60              '2013-01-03'
1          30              '2013-01-03'
```

Result must be:

```
2013-01-01 - 300 (100+200)
2013-01-02 - 500 (300+200)
2013-01-03 - 560 (500+60)
```

Now my SQL looks like (simplified):

```
SELECT 0, SUM (q.FollowersNumber) AS Y FROM 
(SELECT FollowersNumber FROM dbo.Aggregate p WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE p.PublishDate BETWEEN @CurrentPeriod_0_Start AND @CurrentPeriod_0_End AND p.AuthorId not IN 
(SELECT AuthorId FROM dbo.Aggregate WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE PublishDate BETWEEN @PreviousPeriod_0_Start AND @PreviousPeriod_0_End)) AS q 
UNION
SELECT 1, SUM (q.FollowersNumber) AS Y FROM 
(SELECT FollowersNumber FROM dbo.Aggregate p WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE p.PublishDate BETWEEN @CurrentPeriod_1_Start AND @CurrentPeriod_1_End AND p.AuthorId not IN 
(SELECT AuthorId FROM dbo.Aggregate WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE PublishDate BETWEEN @PreviousPeriod_1_Start AND @PreviousPeriod_1_End)) AS q 
etc.
```

After getting that data I count running total of FollowersNumber in C# code.
This query is monstrous and runs slow.
Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: Which db you are using?

Comment: dbo.Aggregate WITH (NOLOCK) It's SQL SERVER :)

Comment: Yes, it's SQL SERVER :) Thanks for UNION ALL.

Comment: Where are your variables `@CurrentPeriod_0_Start`, `@PreviousPeriod_0_Start`, etc, defined? Are they parameters?

Comment: Yes, they are parameters.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff2cf/4

Get Totals history By dates. I don't understand your parameters in query

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      AuthorId INT
    , FollowersNumber INT
    , PublishDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @temp (AuthorId, FollowersNumber, PublishDate)
VALUES 
    (1, 100, '20130101'),
    (2, 200, '20130101'),
    (3, 200, '20130102'),
    (2, 100, '20130102'),
    (4,  60, '20130103'),
    (1,  30, '20130103')

DECLARE 
      @CurrentPeriod_0_Start DATETIME
    , @PreviousPeriod_0_Start DATETIME
    , @CurrentPeriod_0_End DATETIME
    , @PreviousPeriod_0_End DATETIME
    , @CurrentPeriod_1_Start DATETIME
    , @PreviousPeriod_1_Start DATETIME
    , @CurrentPeriod_1_End DATETIME
    , @PreviousPeriod_1_End DATETIME


SELECT 0, Y = SUM(p.FollowersNumber) 
FROM @temp p 
WHERE p.PublishDate BETWEEN @CurrentPeriod_0_Start AND @CurrentPeriod_0_End 
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM @temp p2
        WHERE p2.PublishDate BETWEEN @PreviousPeriod_0_Start AND @PreviousPeriod_0_End
            AND p2.AuthorId = p.AuthorId

    )

UNION ALL

SELECT 1, Y = SUM(p.FollowersNumber)  
FROM @temp p 
WHERE p.PublishDate BETWEEN @CurrentPeriod_1_Start AND @CurrentPeriod_1_End 
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM @temp p2
        WHERE p2.PublishDate BETWEEN @PreviousPeriod_1_Start AND @PreviousPeriod_1_End
            AND p2.AuthorId = p.AuthorId

    )
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. Maybe NOT EXISTS will be faster then NOT IN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query instead of yours.
I wrote this query using CTE in SQL Server. I tested it on your data sample and worked fine.

```
WITH 
RANKINGTABLE AS(
          SELECT [AUTHORID]
              ,[FOLLOWERSNUMBER]
              ,[PUBLISHDATE]
              ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY AUTHORID ORDER BY PUBLISHDATE) IRANK 
          FROM [TESTQUERY].[DBO].[AGGREGATE]
          ),
DAYSUM AS(
SELECT PUBLISHDATE, SUM([FOLLOWERSNUMBER]) DATESUM 
FROM RANKINGTABLE 
WHERE IRANK = 1
GROUP BY PUBLISHDATE
)
SELECT DS1.PUBLISHDATE, 
        (SELECT SUM(DS2.DATESUM) FROM DAYSUM DS2 WHERE DS2.PUBLISHDATE <= DS1.PUBLISHDATE) PTOTAL  
FROM DAYSUM DS1
```

Comment: Interesting variant. But in database dates are not rounded, it looks like 2012-05-22 12:08:18.000, so GROUP BY PUBLISHDATE gives not what I need. And also graph periods can have any duration, 1 day is just for example.

Comment: I wrote this for your data sample but it's so flexible because it doesn't use any parameter and you can write additional sub queries to give your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT 1, SUM(CASE WHEN PublishDate BETWEEN @PreviousPeriod_0_Start AND @PreviousPeriod_0_End
                   THEN NULL ELSE CASE WHEN PublishDate BETWEEN @CurrentPeriod_0_Start AND @CurrentPeriod_0_End
                                       THEN FollowersNumber
                                  END
                   END
              ) AS Y
FROM dbo.Aggregate WITH(NOLOCK)
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, SUM(CASE WHEN PublishDate BETWEEN @PreviousPeriod_1_Start AND @PreviousPeriod_1_End
                   THEN NULL ELSE CASE WHEN PublishDate BETWEEN @CurrentPeriod_1_Start AND @CurrentPeriod_1_End
                                       THEN FollowersNumber
                                  END
                   END
              ) AS Y
FROM dbo.Aggregate WITH(NOLOCK)
etc.
```